# Increment counter based string to search for a string in a list

Tags: python-2.7

My code requirement is something like this.

Using my temp_name variable, I want to search a list. If it does not exist in the list, I would like to use the same. 
If it exists, then I will increment the count by 1 and search again until I find a unique name which does not exist.

```
count = 1
name = department
temp_name = "name" + '-' + str(count)
```

My List is as follows:

```
departments {
department-1
department-7
department-2
department-6
department-9
}
```

Could you please have a look.

I am basically querying all EC2 instances in AWS by their names.

```
import boto3
ec2= boto3.resource('ec2')

# Get information for all running instances
running_instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{
    'Name': 'instance-state-name',
    'Values': ['running']}])

for instance in running_instances:
    for tag in instance.tags:
        if 'Name'in tag['Key']:
            name = tag['Value']
            print name
```

And want to spin a new instance using a unique name which does not exist.

Comment: This list is not valid python code. Do you have an actual program that runs?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of confusion between *names* and *values* of variables here:

```
name = department
temp_name = "name" + '-' + str(count)
```

You are looking for `department-1` etc but `temp_name` actually contains `name-1` etc. Fixing that,

```
departments = ["department-1","department-7","department-2","department-6","department-9"]
count = 1
temp_name = "department-%d" % count
while temp_name in departments:
    count += 1
    temp_name = "department-%d" % count
print temp_name
```

And, after that, probably,

```
departments.append(temp_name)
```